# How would you read lines from a text file into a vector of tuples of i32s?

Tags: rust

This is my attempt:

```
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    //let input = fs::read_to_string("input.txt").unwrap();
    let input = "1, 2\n3, 4\n5, 6";
    let lines: Vec<String> = input.split("\n").map(|s| s.to_string()).collect();

    let data: Vec<(i32, i32)> = lines
        .iter()
        .map(|x| {
            x.split(',')
                .map(|y| y.trim().parse::<i32>().unwrap())
                .collect()
                .unwrap()
        })
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", data);
}
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:13:18
   |
13 |                 .collect()
   |                  ^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `B` declared on the associated function `collect`
   |
   = note: type must be known at this point
help: consider specifying the type argument in the method call
   |
13 |                 .collect::<B>()
   |                         ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't collect into a tuple with `.collect`. One option is to use [`Itertools::collect_tuple`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.collect_tuple) which requires the `itertools` crate:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let input = "1, 2\n3, 4\n5, 6";
    let lines: Vec<String> = input.split("\n").map(|s| s.to_string()).collect();
    let data: Vec<(i32, i32)> = lines
        .iter()
        .map(|x| {
            x.split(',')
                .map(|y| y.trim().parse::<i32>().unwrap())
                .collect_tuple()
                .unwrap()
        })
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", data);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3e8b701b162c05a193e09f7a6cef632a)

Comment: D'oh, I completely missed that `collect` would be trying to create a collection not a tuple.  Thanks.  Is this the best way to turn this string into a vector of tuples more generally or did I miss a simpler way?

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 if you consider not having a dependency to be "simpler", then you could [do this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d5d108484be53fc3592485b196a0a2ed)

Comment: @IvanC I guess I was looking for less verbose, but yeah I see how you'd do it that way.  Thanks!